# Как получить количество заказов в день, неделю, месяц

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Мужики! Есть база

```
статус  заказ дата
1       6555  10.05
1       6565  10.05
2       6535  09.05
2       6135  08.05
2       6235  07.05
```

я могу получить 1 запросом кол-заказов с определенным статусом
но хотелось бы получить еще сколько с этим статусом заказов сегодня, за неделю, месяц
как можно получить 1 запросом, кол-во заказов, в день, в нед, в мес?

надо получить

```
стутус сегодня  вчера  неделя  мес
1      2        0      2       2
2      0        1      3       3
```

можно как то такое сделать 1 запросом? или изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Ну добавьте к `where статус=XYZ` ещё `and where [дата в нужном диапазоне]`. Или вопрос о чём-то другом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

возьмите себе в привычку хранить даты в TIMESTAMP. Вам будет удобнее управлять данными: выбирать за определенный отрезок времени, сортировать и т.д.

А по поводу вашего вопроса, попробуйте так (даты должны быть в TIMESTAMP):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE order_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY order_date DESC

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE order_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ORDER BY order_date DESC

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE order_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

Comment: товарищи плюсующие ошибок в ответе не видят? во-первых, не то, что просили - один запрос, а не три разных. количество, а не все записи в интервале. во-вторых, NOW()-INTERCAL 1 DAY - это не вчера, а с сегодня текущее время по текущее время вчера и т.д... про таймстамп верно, но тоже не в этом смысл, структуру данных никто не видел, вполне возможно это в вопросе просто вручную набитые данные.

Comment: >>NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY - это не вчера, а с сегодня текущее время по текущее время вчера

@Yura Ivanov, не совсем вас понял. это выборка за прошедшие сутки

Comment: Нет, это выборка за период "момент запроса минус 24 часа". Сутки - это другой период.

Comment: а вы видели там значок >= ?? это значит выбрать записи за последние сутки

Comment: [Да?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6ec9/1) Сейчас 2014-05-14, 21:57. Однако, выбираются все четыре записи. Хотя, по вашей логике, должна выбираться только последняя.

Comment: @mountpoint, вчера - это с 00:00:00 по 23:59:59 вчерашнего дня. now() - 24 часа это сутки назад, а не вчера. ну это даже ладно, но одним запросом все равно как вытащить данные вы не показали, а показали как "или изобретать велосипед?"(с) ТС.  
Это все к вопросу о качестве ответов и компетенции плюсующих за компанию. Ведь дело так и закончится комментариями и ответ изменяться не станет, а тем временем ответ дан на совсем не тот вопрос.

Comment: @klopp, извиняюсь INTERVAL 1 DAY действительно не сработал. NOW() - 86400 работает отлично)

Comment: @mountpoint, речь о том, что отсчитывать нужно не `now() минус сутки`, а `от now() до 00:00, назад`.

Comment: @klopp, кто его знает. Может автор хочет сутки назад. Тем более он не говорил за сутки или за день от 00:00. Не люблю неточностей.

Comment: @mountpoint вчера, это вчера, это не от сейчас-24 часа, до сейчас, это именно "вчера", т.к. мы не имеем возможности узнать субъективное "вчера", то мы используем общепринятое - "вчера" заканчивается "сегодня" в 00:00 - 1квант времени. у вас же "вчера" это всегда секунду назад,

Answer (score 3):

Можно:

- Объединяем несколько запросов через union all, потом это объединение суммируем
- В одном запросе через IF в выбираемых полях проверяем нужна запись или нет - 1 или 0.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d265/15)

Какой вариант выбрать зависит от объемов данных и наличия индексов.

Answer (score 0):

Если одним, запросом то как-то так:

```
SELECT t1.<статус> as status,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <твоя_таблица> as t2 WHERE t2.<статус> = t1.<статус> AND t2.<дата> >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) as today,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <твоя_таблица> as t3 WHERE t3.<статус> = t1.<статус> AND t3.<дата> >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) as week,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <твоя_таблица> as t4 WHERE t4.<статус> = t1.<статус> AND t4.<дата> >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as month
 FROM <твоя_таблица> as t1 GROUP BY t1.<статус>
```

Естественно, слова в фигурных скобках надо заменить на название твоей таблицы и соответствующих полей. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce7e4/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Одним запросом, примерно следующая логика:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(условие1, 1, 0)) param1, SUM(IF(условие2, 1, 0)) param2, ...
```

Здесь,

условиеХ - проверка статуса и даты в нужном интервале.

Получается, что если условие проверки на статус и интервал истинно для одельной записи, то в paramX записывается +1.

Для проверки даты удобно использовать INTERVAL.

UPD
Проверку статуса можно вынести в WHERE чтобы получить отдельные записи для каждого статуса. А то что написал вернет все в одной записи.